# Storing language settings of an application in another file

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a Java GUI application in Netbeans and i want to store the language settings of the application in a file, so that when i need to change the interface of the application to another language, i will have to only change the language file. I think i will have to create a file, write the variable names of the GUI components and assign their values. Hovewer i don't have a clue on how to do it. By that i mean, i don't know how to make the application read the file and accept the changes i make. How can i do it?

Comment: Google internationalization along with swing and netbeans... Netbeans makes it rather easy to do so..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file that will take care of pretty much everything, it works like a `Map`.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

try 
{
  properties.setProperty("menu1","File");
  properties.setProperty("menu2","Options");
  properties.setProperty("menu3","Quit");

  properties.store(new FileOutputStream("english.properties"),"English");

  properties.load(new FileInputStream("martian.properties"));

  String menu1 = properties.getProperty("menu1"));

}
catch (IOException ex)
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

A property file looks like this:

```
menu1=File
menu2=Options
menu3=Quit
```

Note that you can use `storeToXML()` and `loadFromXML()` to deal with XML files.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use i18n features of Java platform.
Easiest way to approach it is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html